# Fragment are Messed in Multi-level. How can I handle this?

Tags: android, fragment, addition, fragmenttransaction

Android Fragment are Messed in Multi-level. How can I handle this? 3-level's fragment is Messed during FragmentTransaction.add() and FragmentTransaction.remove() methods. When I back from 3-level to 1-level and I come from 1-level to 2-level, It showed the old 2-level's fragment and it should showed the new one 2-level's fragment.

Comment: What do you mean by "messed" and "multi-level"? Diagrams would help.

Comment: messed its meaning confusion。 multi-level is meaning multilayer。

Comment: I had handled this problem。Thank you！